# I want to use fluent-ffmpeg module

Tags: javascript, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to ask about video convert in JS. I chose the [`fluent-ffmpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) module to do that.

But, when I imported that in JS file, something happen like the picture below:

[image: fluent-ffmpeg import hints]

So, I went in package.json file, and this module exists in file:

[image: content of package.json]

What's the problem in this case? I guess it is problem about version, but what do I have to check first?

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not provided pictures of text.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.. I will try to be carefull!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your package.json is correct the thing you need to do is add @types/fluent-ffmpeg to your dev dependencies to get hinting !
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fluent-ffmpeg

```
npm i --save-dev @types/fluent-ffmpeg
```